# Using Template Class in my Dll

Tags: c++, templates, dll

following situation:
I have in one dll a template class Point

```
namespace Image
{
     template<typename T> class Point
     {
     .
     .
     .
```

and tring to use this class in another dll. The class looks like:

```
//Base.h
template<typename T> class Point;

class Base{
    Point<double> _Point;
};

//Child.h
#include "Base.h"
class Child : public Base{
    Child(Point<double> pt);
    doSth();
}

//Child.cpp
#include "Child.h"
#include "Point.h"

Child::Child(Point<double> pt){
    _Point = pt;                   
}
Child::dosth(){
    Point<double> p  = _Point;  // In this Row i get an "undefined type 'Point<double>' Error
}
```

Any ideas why i get the error?
is my idea totally wrong to forward declare the Point-Class in the header file and make the include in the .cpp ?

Thank you very much, have a nice day!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but don't use symbols with a leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter (like `_Point`). Those symbols are reserved in all scopes. [See this questions and answers for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: As for your problem, isn't it `Image::Point<...>` (you're missing the namespace)?

Comment: sure just forget. In both cpp i have  using namespace Image;

Comment: That's one reason why it's so important to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

With the forward declaration you have in `Base.h` it doesn't matter if you used `using namespace Image;` first, the template class you declare in `Base.h` is still in the *global* namespace and not in the `Image` namespace. And that declaration will take precedence over the one in the `Image` namespace.

So there are really two solutions here: Either explicitly use `Image::Point`, or remove the forward declaration in `Base.h` (and include the header file where `Image::Point<>` is defined).

Comment: I tried this before. If i do this Visual Studio says "variable 'Image::Point [with T=double]' is not a type name" at the parameter of the constructor in 'Child.h'

Comment: @NeumannM And you *did* include the correct header file that defines the class?

Comment: I think yes because the right file is listening in the External Dependencies of my project